# Select with generated values and subqueries

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a product db with the following tables:

- Products*
- Certificates*
- Reports*
- Descriptions*
- Products_Certificates*
- Certificates_Reports
- Certificates_Descriptions

There are many-to-many-relationships between products and certificates, certificates and reports, and certificates and descriptions.

Every table marked with * has a column with a timestamp (can be null).

**Desired Output**

All columns of products table + a new column with

- 0, if the row's timestamp is null
- 1, if the row's timestamp is not null, but any of the related entities' (or their related entities') timestamp is null
- 2, if the row's timestamp is not null and all of the related entities' (or their related entities') timestamp is not null

I don't even have the slightest bit of an idea how to solve this.

---

This is the query that shows how all tables join together:

```
   SELECT Products.*
     FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Products_Certificates
       ON Products_Certificates.ProductNumber = Products.ProductNumber
LEFT JOIN Certificates
       ON Certificates.ID = Products_Certificates.CertificateID
LEFT JOIN Certificates_Reports
       ON Certificates_Reports.CertificateID = Certificates.ID
LEFT JOIN Reports
       ON Reports.ID = Certificates_Reports.ReportID
LEFT JOIN Certificates_Descriptions
       ON Certificates_Descriptions.CertificateID = Certificates.ID
LEFT JOIN Descriptions
       ON Descriptions.ID = Certificates_Descriptions.DescriptionID
```

Comment: Can you edit the original question and add a query that shows how all the tables join together?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the original question and added the query.

Comment: Have you looked into using a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012. I looked into the case expression, but I don't know how to say "if value of column x in all rows of this sub query is 2".

Comment: @pinki I updated the answer to show a working example.

Comment: Your "example" has no subqueries so it appears that you want something like `case when Products.UnspecifiedColumnThatContainsTheTimestamp is NULL then 0 else when Certificates.UnspecifiedColumnThatContainsTheTimestamp is NULL or Reports.UnspecifiedColumnThatContainsTheTimestamp is NULL or ... then 1 else 2 end as ANewColumn`. Since your code only returns values from `Products` there will likely be many rows with various calculated values that are otherwise indistinguishable.

Comment: From [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "The **timestamp** syntax is deprecated."

Answer (score 0):

Using mocked up data and written in SQL Server 2014, here is some code to get you started -

```
 declare @Products table
(
  ProductNumber int not null,
  Created date
);

insert into @Products values
(1, '1/7/2019'),
(2, null),
(3, '3/4/2019'),
(4, '3/7/2019');

declare @Products_Certificates table
(
  CertificateID int not null,
  ProductNumber int not null,
  Created date
);

insert into @Products_Certificates values
(50, 1, null),
(51, 1, '2/2/2019'),
(52, 3, '2/2/2019'),
(53, 4, null),
(54, 4, null);

declare @Certificates table
(
  ID int not null,
  Created date
);

insert into @Certificates values
(50, null),
(51, '3/1/2019'),
(52, null);

with
detail as
(
  SELECT
  p.ProductNumber,
  p.Created,
  pc.CertificateID,
  c.ID,
  Products_Certs_Date_Flag = iif(pc.Created is null, 0, 1),
  Certificates_Date_Flag = iif(c.Created is null, 0, 1)
  FROM @Products p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @Products_Certificates pc     ON pc.ProductNumber = p.ProductNumber
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @Certificates c               ON c.ID = pc.CertificateID
  /*
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @Certificates_Reports cr      ON cr.CertificateID = c.ID --no timestamp in this table
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @Reports r                    ON r.ID = cr.ReportID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @Certificates_Descriptions cd ON cd.CertificateID = c.ID --no timestamp in this table
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @Descriptions d               ON d.ID = cd.DescriptionID;
  */
),
summary as
(
  select
  ProductNumber,
  Created,
  DateStatus = iif(Products_Certs_Date_Flag + Certificates_Date_Flag > 0, 'date exists', 'no date')
  from detail
),
pivoted as
(
  select
  ProductNumber,
  Created,
  [date exists],
  [no date]
  from summary
  pivot (count(DateStatus) for DateStatus in ([date exists], [no date])) p
)
select
ProductNumber,
Created,
Outcome =
case
  when Created is null then 0
  when [no date] > 0 then 1
  else 2
end
from pivoted
order by
ProductNumber;
```

Here are screen shots of the intermediate result sets in the CTEs:
detail
[image]

summary
[image]

pivoted
[image]

And here are the final results:
[image]

More work will be necessary to make the other 4 tables active in the `detail` CTE.  The code above gives you an idea of how to tackle the problem outlined in the original post.  Also, test the `case` statement carefully - it may be necessary to add other criteria once you run this against live data if the 1 and 2 values are not being assigned correctly.